# Pass a function as parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I have seen people doing this:

```
usort($array, function() {
    //...
});
```

How can I write similar implementation using my own function? For eg:

```
runIt(function() {
     //...
});
```

and implementation of `runIt`:

```
function runIt() {
    // do something with passed function
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`function() {}` is called anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and can be invoked using the param name. For eg:

```
function runIt($param) {
    $param();
}
runIt(function() {
    echo "Hello world!";
});
```

If you are interested in var-args then:

```
function runIt() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $param) {
        $param();
    }
}
runIt(function() {
    echo "hello world";
});
```

Comment: Downvoter: Mind explaining the reason for down-vote?

Comment: It's a very nice answer. Therefore I am curious too, why it has been downvoted.